# How to enable and disable the input file when switching radiobatton?

Tags: html, angular

I have a form, and I need to unable and disable control  in the same form depending on the radio button position

```
<form [formGroup]="service.form" #signUpForm="ngForm" class="normal-form">
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    <mat-radio-group formControlName="role">
        <mat-radio-button value="1">Patient</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="2">Doctor</mat-radio-button>
     </mat-radio-group>
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    <input type="file" #Image accept="image/*" [disabled]="service.form.role==1">
</form>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get `role` on `service.form`. `service.form` will have a `value` property on which you'll get this `role` property.

Just use `service.form.value.role` instead of `service.form.role`

```
<form [formGroup]="form" #signUpForm="ngForm" class="normal-form">
    <mat-radio-group formControlName="role">
        <mat-radio-button value="1">Patient</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="2">Doctor</mat-radio-button>
     </mat-radio-group>
    <br>
    <input type="file" #Image accept="image/*" [disabled]="form.value.role==1">
</form>
```

Here's a [**Sample Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-disable-file-input-on-radio?file=app/radio-overview-example.html) for your ref.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the reference to role element and use reference to disable and enable the other control.

```
<form [formGroup]="service.form" #signUpForm="ngForm" class="normal-form">
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    <mat-radio-group #role formControlName="role">
        <mat-radio-button value="1">Patient</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="2">Doctor</mat-radio-button>
     </mat-radio-group>
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    <input type="file" #Image accept="image/*" [disabled]="role.value==1">
</form>
```

Comment: I changed [disabled]="service.form.role==1" to [disabled]="role.value==1" and added #role, but it did not help me. Сan something else be needed?

Comment: Since the value is in string use `[disabled]="role.value=='1'" `

Comment: Angular material might be working in different way. Try the solution given by @SiddAjmera. It looks promising one.